# Ember.js, "modifier" property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Observe the following demo:

*(app.js)*

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      value1: "A"
    });
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    changeOutside: function () {
      this.set("model.value1", "B");
    }
  }
});

App.TestTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  _value1: null,
  value1: function (_, newValue) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      this.set("_value1", newValue);
    }
    var res = "PREFIXED " + (this.get("_value1") || "");
    return res;
  }.property(),

  actions: {
    changeInside: function () {
      this.set("value1", "C");
    }
  }
});
```

*(index.hbs)*

```
<h3>Inside controller</h3>
<button type="button" {{action "changeOutside"}}>Change</button>
1: {{model.value1}}<br/>
<hr />
{{test-test value1=model.value1}}
```

*(components/test-test)*

```
<h5>Inside component</h5>
<button type="button" {{action "changeInside"}}>Change</button>
1: {{value1}}<br/>
```

Working jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zejujequco/1/edit?html,js,output

So, the idea is to have a component that can take a bound property and modify it.

As you can see in the fiddle, it doesn't works. The modified value is displayed correctly inside the component, but remains unmodified in the controller.

Playing around with modifier buttons reveals that Ember expects the property set to be the property returned, at least as far as bindings are concerned.
That is, the modified value is not immediately propagated back after the "set" operation. It is only sent after the second set operation. Unfortunately, in this case, this completely breaks the illusion of "bindings just work".

Not sure if this is a bug, but I doubt it. Seems simple enough, someone would have caught it before.

The question is, how do I get this to work?

I know I can do it with two properties: "inputValue" where the controller gives its base value in and "outputValue" where it gets the modified value out (and then tie them together somehow at the controller level).

But that's super clunky. I'm sort of hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: what is ur use case? There might be better alternative. Ember is slowly getting rid of 2 way data binding. The current idea is bindings down and actions up.

Comment: Component is an editor for a list of things. The two way binding is a way to get the list in and results out

Comment: Is there a reason you're implementing the property as a computed property? If you remove that it appears to work.. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/famevateya/1/edit?js,output .. It seems odd that you're implementing a custom setter like this.. When I click changeInside, it changes the vale to `PREFIXED C` which is propagated up to the controller, which is changed to `PREFIXED C` which is then propagated back down to the component where it adds `PREFIXED` at the start

Comment: Also, the behaviour I experienced was different to what you described - for me the controller property was modified in the JSBin.

Comment: @jmurphyau, I need to compute different return values in that property. Computed property is the whole point of the demo. "ChangeInside" is just to show how the value is propagating, it's not really the point of the widget. In reality, I could correct for this behavior. When I first start the demo, I see "A" inside the controller and "PREFIXED A" in component. You see something different?

Comment: I see `A`/`PREFIXED A`.. When I click on change in the controller it changes to `B`/`PREFIXED B` and when I click change in the component it changes to `PREFIXED C`/`PREFIXED PREFIXED C`

Comment: @jmurphyau it should be `PREFIXED A` in both places. That's the point, it's not being propagated properly.

Comment: So you want the value to go from A (controller), to PREFIXED A (component) which should propagate PREFIXED A to the controller.. Which would then propagate PREFIXED A (controller) to PREFIXED PREFIXED A (component) which would propagate back up - you will be stuck in a never ending loop adding PREFIXED at the start of the string..

Comment: Yes obviously I would have to detect loop and prevent it at some point. Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Using bindings and computed properties in combination for this doesn't seem right.. Is there a there a reason you can't set the computed property on the model? Alternatively, if you need something external to the model (e.g. your component) managing a property of the model, I would provide the component with the model object and use observers